# From SVG to PNG with Batik: an issue with multiline text

Tags: java, svg, batik

I am converting an SVG into a PNG image using Batik, but text that goes on mutiple lines is not rendered correctly. It can occur, in a non-deterministic way, that the text itself is not centered anymore on the final image.

As an example, consider this part of the starting SVG:

[image]

This is the correct rendering, that I wish to obtain in the PNG too. The resulting PNG, by the way, looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the text into the top green box is not centered anymore.

This is the piece of SVG that define that (suspecting a fonts issue, I have also tried by removing all the `font-family=""`, with no effect):

```
  <g transform="translate(184.68 -0.600364)">
     <text fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" fill-opacity="1" font-family="Kievit Pro" font-size="10px" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(48 0.429996)">
        <tspan dy="1em" x="0">A simple activity, with</tspan>
        <tspan dy="1.5em" x="0">a text that goes on t</tspan>
     </text>
  </g>
```

If it could help, this is the code I'm using for the conversion:

```
static byte[] convertToPng(byte[] byteSvgSmall) throws TranscoderException, IOException {
    if (byteSvgSmall != null) {

        byte[] byteImagePng = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream targetStream = null;

        try {
            targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteSvgSmall);
            TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(targetStream);

            PNGTranscoder transcoder = new PNGTranscoder();
            transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, new Float(diagramWidthInPixelsForPdf));

            TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(baos);
            transcoder.transcode(input, output);

            byte[] byteOutput = baos.toByteArray();
            byteImagePng = new byte[byteOutput.length];
            bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
            bais.read(byteImagePng);
            targetStream.close();
            baos.flush();
            return byteImagePng;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            BeanFactory
                    .getLogger()
                    .error(SVGTransformer.class,
                            "An error occurred. A null byte[] will be returned",
                            e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (bais != null) bais.close();
            if (baos != null) baos.close();
            if (targetStream != null) targetStream.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then, with the returned byte[]:

```
if (pngBytes != null) {
   BufferedImage final_img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(pngBytes));
   File output_file = new File(imagepath);
   ImageIO.write(final_img, "png", output_file);
}
```

Thank you so much for any insight.

Comment: @Andreaジーティーオー I wasn't able to reproduce the issue. I'm using 1.9.1

 
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/batik-all -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
          <artifactId>batik-all</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.1</version>
          <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>

Comment: @EzekielBaniaga: Thank you so much for your try, really appreciated. Responding to Dave Jarvis too, I am compiling with Java 1.6, batik-all-1.7.jar; I don't know which tool generates the SVG; I receive it from another team, in order to put it into a PDF with Apache POI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I have finally found the real issue, thanks to a post on [this Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BATIK-1017). The trailing and ending whitespaces, into `tspans`' text, cause the Batik rasterizer to misinterpret the content.

By scanning the tspan Elements, and setting a trimmed version of the text:

```
for (int tspanCounter = 0; tspanCounter < tspanList.getLength(); tspanCounter++) {
   Node tspan = tspanList.item(tspanCounter);
   tspan.setTextContent(actParts[tspanCounter].trim());
}
```

I obtain the correct result. In the images below, you can see the result with and without...the simple `trim()` call!

**Wrong version (whitespaces in the tspan's content)**

[image]

**"Right" version (whitespaces trimmed in the tspan's content)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your svg and the file (at least on my computer) doesn't quite fit the text within the bounds of the green boxes (there is a bit of overflow, which is clipped). I'm not sure if this is a platform problem since your screen shot shows the text with a bit of margin (whereas in my case, opening with GIMP, the text goes beyond).

As such, I modified your svg such that all the 10px font sizes were reduced to 9px (in order to fit everything in the squares).

I then ran your code with the java-8-openjdk-amd64, the svg provided and the following dependencies:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-transcoder', version: '1.9.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'xmlgraphics-commons', version: '2.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', name: 'batik-codec', version: '1.9.1'
```

The `TEST1` box rendered similar, but not identical, in my png as in yours:

```
A simple activity, with
  a text that goes on t
```

I then modified the xml node, changing the second line from "a text that goes on t" to "a text that". This time the second line was centered.

```
A simple activity, with
     a text that
```

I then put the original text back in the node and changed the font family for the box to `Lucida Sans` and size to 7px  (my modified node here below).

```
<text fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" fill-opacity="1" font-family="Lucida Sans" font-size="7px" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(48 0.429996)">
    <tspan dy="1em" x="0">A simple activity, with</tspan>
    <tspan dy="1.5em" x="0">a text that goes on t</tspan>
</text>
```

This time it was centered. What have you tried? What results do you get if you try the above (changing the font-size and/or font-family)? I also used 1000px for the `KEY_WIDTH` transcoding hint if that might change anything in your case.

Comment: Hi William, thank you, really appreciated. Probably, on your machine, the text is rendered in a different way 'cause the Kievit Pro font is missing. Even in my case, the final rendering is a bit different, and seems to lose that font in the conversion (as in the second image of my question: that is the resulting png, placed into a pdf with Apache POI). So, if I understood correctly, your advice is to reduce the font-size with a massive replace. I try and let you know. Maybe, Batik encounters a text which is too long for its container, and has problems in rendering it.

Comment: Hi, yes, I suggest trying different `font-family` and/or `font-size` values. I updated the answer accordingly. It's a bit hit-and-miss since I wasn't able to reproduce your exact starting condition but it seems like a rendering issue within the library. I'm not sure what kind of font `Kevit Pro` is but `Lucida Sans` should be "java friendly". Let me know how it goes.

Comment: yes, I cannot be sure about it because I don't know what Batik does under the hood. But, manipulating the font-size just before the conversion, seems to solve the issue. Maybe there really is a problem with placing the text into a container that does "fit" it no more. I think that the next step would be trying to keep the font-family in the conversion. By now...thank you so much (and also to the others that tried to help)!